# Differences between these 2 lines of code

Tags: javascript

I'm learning some more ES6:

```
const _findCartItem = ( item ) => {
    return _cartItems.find( cartItem => cartItem.id === item.id);
};
```

converts to:

```
var _findCartItem = function _findCartItem(item){
    return _cartItems.find(function(cartItem){
        return cartItem.id == item.id;
    })
};
```

However, is there a difference between this and the following? Is this dual declaration necessary?

```
var _findCartItem = function(item){
    return _cartItems.find(function(cartItem){
        return cartItem.id == item.id;
    })
};
```

Comment: But - `var aa = function bb() {}; aa.name` outputs `"bb"`

Comment: @userqwert if you do `var func = function fuc(){}` the function is _named_. It just means that it will show up in debug tools and stack traces with the name `func` as opposed to `(anonymous block)`. The fat arrow function names the function after the variable it's assigned to, so it's similar to doing `var func = () => {};`

Comment: @vlaz that's very helpful, post it as an answer! Or not, some dude closed it. So a *named* funtion literally just has a *name* property?

Comment: @userqwert yes, that's it. It doesn't change anything than debug output. Should be noted that you can name your function anything, e.g., `var a = function b() {}` is _valid_ - however, you cannot now do `b()` as that's not what the function is assigned to.

Comment: @vlaz brill, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceitualy, no, both will do the same. Syntactically, yes. First one is passing a reference of a named function to a variable, second a anonymous function.

Using first option is prefereble because you get better call stacks.